# Sql to update active row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below two tables
EMpbasetable:

```
Skey,EmployeeNumber,Startdate,EndDate,Active

3,123,2019/06/10,2019/10/27,0

4,123,2019/10/28,4712/12/31,1
```

EmpIncTable:

```
Skey,EmployeeNumber,Startdate,EndDate

9,123,2019/06/10,2019/10/17


10,123,2019/10/18,4712/12/31
```

My requirement is skey 9,10 insert in EMpbasetable table and 3,4 active indicator changed to 2. Skey 9 to 0 and  10 change to 1

```
3,123,2019/06/10,2019/10/27,2

4,123,2019/10/28,4712/12/31,2

9,123,2019/06/10,2019/10/17,0

10,123,2019/10/18,4712/12/31,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
insert into EMpbasetable (Skey, EmployeNumber, Startdate, EndDate, Active)
   select Skey, EmployeeNumber, StartDate, EndDate, case when skey=9 then 0 when skey=10 then 1 end 
   from EmpIncTable;
update EMpbasetable set active=2 when skey in (3,4)
```